# Como adicionar mais linhas a uma classe em Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

Comecei a me aventurar no mundo das rubygems. Estou desenvolvendo uma gem para gerar os assets da minha aplicação ao estilo twitter bootstrap, já que pretendo reaproveitar o meu código front-end. Tudo que eu preciso fazer é colocar os assets nos lugares corretos, adicionar alguns helpers e efetuar algumas configurações. Várias gems que funcionam dessa forma, fazem adições ao arquivo application.js/.css no momento da instalação. Por exemplo, o bootstrap, quando o comando `rails g bootstrap:install` é executado, os assets são transferidos para o devido path e um require é automaticamente adicionado ao application.css e ao application.js.

Quero fazer algo semelhante, só que em um ponto específico do arquivo application.rb. Sendo mais exato, o que eu quero é adicionar mais pastas ao path de assets. O arquivo é mais ou menos assim:

```
class Application < Rails::Application

end
```

Eu preciso que fique tipo assim:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
     config.assets.paths << 'path/para/a/pasta'
end
```

Mas como eu faria para garantir que sempre esse conteúdo será adicionado dentro da definição da classe? Digo, simplesmente fazer adições no arquivo é simples, mas nesse caso não posso adicionar fora do escopo da classe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns exemplos bem legais de como fazer isso, dos quais eu destacaria um da gem responders: https://github.com/plataformatec/responders/blob/master/lib/generators/responders/install_generator.rb

Nesse caso, ele usa a funcao inject_into_class, que vem de Rails::Generators::Base, e o seu codigo ficaria assim:

```rb
def add_assets
  inject_into_class "config/application.rb", "Application", <<-RUBY
    config.assets.paths << 'path/para/a/pasta'
  RUBY
end
```

Acho que bastaria colocar isso em um generator...

Comment: Valeeeeeu! É isso mesmo que eu preciso!